# How to change the LED toggle speed in Contiki?

Tags: contiki

Im trying to implement a UDP client mote using cc2650 launchpad and I need to modify the code to toggle the led once a "hello message" is sent. The normal leds_toggle( ) command works but it takes a long time to turn of the led once it lit. How to solve this problem? Any Ideas?

Comment: I assume you are using an example project, in case you are, which one? For example: `/contiki/examples/cc26xx/cc26xx-web-demo/cetic-6lbr-client.c`

Comment: Actually I used the following example. 
https://sunmaysky.blogspot.com/2017/10/using-cc13xxcc26xx-running-contiki-os.html?m=0

Somehow I was able to find a solution by introducing a delay command instead of toggling.